# Maven fail with varargs parameter

Tags: java, maven, junit4, variadic-functions

I'm trying to create the unit test for my application but unfortunately I got one strange problem.

I have one method with two parameters and the last it's a varargs classes:

```
public JsonApi convertStringToJsonApi(String json, Class<?>... classes)
```

My test is extremely simple:

```
jsonApiString = "{ 'data': [ { 'type': 'TEST', 'id': '1', 'attributes': { 'attr1': 'Attribute', 'attr2': 200, 'attr3': { 'attr': { 'Model': 'XPTO', 'License': '85599' } } }, 'relationships': { 'name': 'Miguel', 'age': '30' } } ] }";

// jsonApiObjectResult = jsonMaker.convertStringToJsonApi(jsonApiString. EntityTestAttr1.class, EntityTestRels.class);
jsonApiObjectResult = jsonMaker.convertStringToJsonApi(jsonApiString, new Class<?>[] { EntityTestAttr1.class, EntityTestRels.class });

Assert.assertNotNull(jsonApiObjectResult);
Assert.assertNotNull(jsonApiObjectResult.getData().get(0));
Assert.assertEquals("1", jsonApiObjectResult.getData().get(0).getId());
Assert.assertEquals("TEST", jsonApiObjectResult.getData().get(0).getType());
Assert.assertEquals("Attribute", ((EntityTestAttr1) jsonApiObjectResult.getData().get(0).getAttr()).getAttr1());
Assert.assertEquals(new BigDecimal(200), ((EntityTestAttr1) jsonApiObjectResult.getData().get(0).getAttr()).getAttr2());
Assert.assertEquals("XPTO", ((EntityTestAttr1) jsonApiObjectResult.getData().get(0).getAttr()).getAttr3().getAttr().get("Model"));
Assert.assertEquals("85599", ((EntityTestAttr1) jsonApiObjectResult.getData().get(0).getAttr()).getAttr3().getAttr().get("License"));
Assert.assertEquals("Miguel", ((EntityTestRels) jsonApiObjectResult.getData().get(0).getRels()).getName());
Assert.assertEquals("30", ((EntityTestRels) jsonApiObjectResult.getData().get(0).getRels()).getAge());
```

When I run the unit test with eclipse all work perfect and the test get success; however, with maven I get an exception "java.lang.NullPointerException".

Maven stack:

```
Tests run: 12, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.075 sec <<< FAILURE! - in org.test.TestAux
convertAllResourcesStringToJsonApiTest(org.test.Maker)  Time elapsed: 0.063 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.test.Maker.convertAllResourcesStringToJsonApiTest(TestAux.java:208)
```

I believe it's because the varargs for when I use only one class in the second parameter (varargs) then works fine and maven gets success.

Why? I don't understand! :(

Comment: which Java maven is running with?

Comment: Please show us the 208 line, and also why when calling varargs you are creating the array?

Comment: @KirilS. Maven info:
Apache Maven 3.2.1 (ea8b2b07643dbb1b84b6d16e1f08391b666bc1e9; 2014-02-14T17:37:52+00:00)
Maven home: /Users/nunobento/Apache-Maven-3.2.1
Java version: 1.7.0_60, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: pt_PT, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.10.5", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"

Comment: @krzyk The line 208 is the line I call method.
jsonApiObjectResult = jsonMaker.convertStringToJsonApi(jsonApiString, new Class<?>[] { EntityTestAttr1.class, EntityTestRels.class });

Comment: Where does `jasonMaker` come from? Have you checked that it is not `null` at that point?

Comment: @GeroldBroser jsonMaker it's a singleton. I instanced the object using Before junit annotation.